# Count of sub-strings that contain character X at least once. E.g Input: str = “abcd”, X = ‘b’ Output: 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This question was asked in an exam but my code (given below) passed just 2 cases out of 7 cases.

Input Format : single line input seperated by comma

Input: str = “abcd,b”

Output: 6

“ab”, “abc”, “abcd”, “b”, “bc” and “bcd” are the required sub-strings.

```
def slicing(s, k, n):
    loop_value = n - k + 1
    res = []
    for i in range(loop_value):
        res.append(s[i: i + k])

    return res


x, y = input().split(',')
n = len(x)
res1 = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    res1 += slicing(x, i, n)

count = 0
for ele in res1:
    if y in ele:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Can you share the question, input and desired output?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: question updated, please help me to resolve the issues in my code @wjandrea

Comment: @Rahul You're missing the actual output. And what is your question, anyway?

Comment: uploaded the exact question what it was asked in the exam. Please check now @NisargShah

Comment: What's *your* question?

Answer (score 1):

When the target string (`ts`) is found in the string `S`, you can compute the number of substrings containing that instance by multiplying the number of characters before the target by the number of characters after the target (plus one on each side).

This will cover all substrings that contain this instance of the target string leaving only the "after" part to analyse further, which you can do recursively.

```
def countsubs(S,ts):
    if ts not in S: return 0                   # shorter or no match
    before,after = S.split(ts,1)               # split on target
    result = (len(before)+1)*(len(after)+1)    # count for this instance
    return result + countsubs(ts[1:]+after,ts) # recurse with right side


print(countsubs("abcd","b")) # 6
```

This will work for single character and multi-character targets and will run much faster than checking all combinations of substrings one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without recursion:

```
def my_function(s):
    l, target = s.split(',')
    result = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(l)+1):
            ss = l[i] + l[i+1:j]
            if target in ss:
                result.append(ss)
    return f'count = {len(result)}, substrings = {result}'

print(my_function("abcd,b"))
#count = 6, substrings = ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd']
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, this should help

```
from itertools import combinations
output = []
initial = input('Enter string and needed letter seperated by commas:  ') #Asking for input
list1 = initial.split(',') #splitting the input into two parts i.e the actual text and the letter we want common in output
text = list1[0]
final = [''.join(l) for i in range(len(text)) for l in combinations(text, i+1)] #this is the core part of our code, from this statement we get all the available combinations of the set of letters (all the way from 1 letter combinations to nth letter)
for i in final:
    if 'b' in i:
        output.append(i) #only outputting the results which have the required letter/phrase in it
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation does not help anyone learn anything.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.. Would remember to put a detailed explanation the next time I answer, thanks for the feedback though :)

Comment: You can always edit this time. Waiting for "next time" sounds a bit disingenuous.